# Perfect a regex for finding @username tags

Tags: php, regex

Im using a system to get @twitter like names and the following regex is near perfect:

```
(?<![^\s<>])@([^\s<>]+)
```

The problem I have found is if there are punctuation marks after the name

So for example:

- Hey @mark  ===> matches @mark        ***(This is what we want)***
- Hey @mark.  ===> matches @mark.
- Hey @mark, you're nice  ===> matches @mark,
- Hey @mark!!!! I didn't think of that   ===>  matches @mark!!!!

Obviously we only want to match the username and not the punctuation marks.  The caveat is that some usernames have these period inside the username, for example

For example, these are all legitimate usernames

mark.markus

mark@gmail.com

mark_markus@gmail.com

*EDIT*  We are using a lookbehind, if the above usernames are used with an @ infront of them, they should match, but without the @ in front then an email address should actually not match.   @mark_markus@gmail.com should match mark_markus@gmail.com, but if someone typed plain old mark_markus@gmail.com we dont want gmail.com to match.

Any ideas on how to modify the regex to account for the various punctuation marks that could be used?

Comment: I think you can't achieve this depending on ^(some black list chars), its better to create your pattern using white-list of chars such as (^[a-z]) the user mustname start with a-z, and allowed to has .,- in the middle, etc...

Comment: Having punctuation, besides underscores is not a good idea IMO.  What if some one says: "Hey @mark!" referring @mark and not @mark!.  They script would tag @mark! instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this:

```
(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)
```

I have replaced `[^\s<>]` with `[\w@]`, which is a bit more restrictive.  `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscores.  If there are any other characters you specifically need to allow, add them to each character class.

This group: `(?:\.\w+)*` Allows one or more periods to be part of the username, but only if they are followed immediately by word characters.  Note that `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.  It is useful when you want to group things for logical purposes, but don't need to capture the result.

**Update:** [see a working example](http://regex101.com/r/pG1fK5).

Comment: You may need to tweak this, according to regex hero it doesn't match the last example.

Comment: Dan, this is for twitter like meaning its my own usernames but I wanted to have it function similar to twitter's @ system.   Your code is near perfect except in the case of an email address, so if someone were to type in mark@gmail.com it doesnt match, perfect.  BUT if someone types @mark@gmail.com it only matches @mark, it should match mark@gmail.com as its actually is username, not just an email address that is being typed in.  Confused yet? :)

Comment: @TheGreatCO, that matches `@mark` for me, which is what I thought was intended.

Comment: According to your new example, the username mark!!!! is invalid.  It must include punctuation unless he changed his mind.

Comment: @MichaelGarrison, the point of the question was to specifically exclude punctuation from being part of the match, except that periods could be part of a username.

Comment: Then perhaps this is a typo? "Hey @mark!!!! I didn't think of that ===> matches @mark!!!!"

Comment: @MichaelGarrison dan is correct, he answered my question as asked.   However dan1111 it did bring up another question, if it can be easily solved or not?  What if the punctuation is in the middle, for example if the persons name is mark!markus it should match, but not match mark!!     Is this possible?

Comment: @Mark, I updated the regex to also allow a ! in the middle.  You should be able to easily see how to allow other characters.  (Note, if you post a question about regexes in the future, it is good to think about all the characters you wish to allow/disallow and include a comprehensive set of examples of things that should match and not match).

Comment: @MichaelGarrison, the question is a bit unclear.  The first example shows something matching correctly.  The next three show things matching incorrectly, including punctuation when they should not.

Comment: @dan1111 no problem, thanks for all your efforts!  the latest edit actually breaks it for email addresses now, your just previously posted answer was the most correct one ==> (?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:\.[\w@]+)*)